# Migrating from webpack to angular-cli

Tags: django, webpack, angular-cli

we are using angular and django BFF as single project.

We are trying to migrate from webpack to angular-cli
In webpack we are using webpack-bundle-tracker plugin which generates webpack-stats.json file in dist directory on doing "npm run build"

## webpack.config.js

```html
plugins: [
      new BundleTracker({path: __dirname, filename: './assets/webpack-stats.json'})
    ]
```

Output in webpack-stats.json looks like below:

```html
{
  "status":"done",
  "chunks":{
   "app":[{
      "name":"app-0828904584990b611fb8.js",
      "publicPath":"http://localhost:3000/assets/bundles/app-0828904584990b611fb8.js",
      "path":"/home/user/project-root/assets/bundles/app-0828904584990b611fb8.js"
    }]
  }
}
```

Above file is read by Django (django-webpack-loader)

My question is
How can we generate webpack-stats.json file using angular cli. I tried to do below in package.json file which generates stats.json but file format is different.

"ng build --prod --aot=false --stats-json"